# Does Predators' Hour apply to creatures that come into play after it resolves?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I control [Adeline, Resplendent Cathar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Adeline%2C%20Resplendent%20Cathar) and play [Predators' Hour](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Predators%27%20Hour), does the effect apply to the token Adeline produces while attacking?

Answer (score 5):

No, it only applies to creatures you had when it resolved.

> 611.2c If a continuous effect generated by the resolution of a spell or ability modifies the characteristics or changes the controller of any objects, the set of objects it affects is determined when that continuous effect begins. After that point, the set won’t change. (Note that this works differently than a continuous effect from a static ability.)

And to be clear that Predators' Hour does modify the characteristics of objects:

> 109.3. An object’s characteristics are name, mana cost, color, color indicator, card type, subtype, supertype, rules text, **abilities**, power, toughness, loyalty, hand modifier, and life modifier. Objects can have some or all of these characteristics. Any other information about an object isn’t a characteristic. For example, characteristics don’t include whether a permanent is tapped, a spell’s target, an object’s owner or controller, what an Aura enchants, and so on.

So if it were a static ability, rather than an effect generated by the resolution of your spell, then it would apply to all creatures you control at all times.